# iOS iPad tablet renders viewport incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, viewport

I have a fixed width site 960px to be exact. I have scaled up all the content to work on a mobile phone. I can use a fixed-width viewport and it works beautifully but google keeps giving me errors that I shouldn't use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=961">` google wants me to use `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` or a similar non-fixed width instead or my site will not be considered mobile friendly to google. When I do what google says to my viewport the site scrolls off the right side of the screen in portrait view. Need help on how to make what google wants work with an iPad and ios?

Comment: If your site isn't responsive, should you be setting that? Just including it in your site doesn't make it mobile-friendly. In fact, using it on pages that don't have responsive/adaptive code could cause rendering issues like what you're describing.

Comment: My content scales up for mobile but maintains the same 960 width, best we can do before Google's April deadline. Going responsive would require a total rewrite of everything. Yes you have to set the viewport per google's April 21 deadline for all sites to be mobile friendly. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/02/finding-more-mobile-friendly-search.html  If you don't set the viewport then they assume your site is not mobile friendly. Even if the content scales up for mobile like ours does.  Basically we scale up all the content and images for mobile devices using media queries.

Comment: It is highly likely that your site is not mobile friendly. Keep using <meta name="viewport" content="width=961">. Using content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" just makes your site even less mobile friendly. It is really sounding like you just want to trick Google into thinking your site is mobile friendly.

Comment: Google is not that dumb ha! No I'm trying to get our site to display correctly on iPads. Here's the site, we just have the menu to go and it will be fully mobile friendly. http://www.homewetbar.com We need a solution to the viewport question I posed though. As you can see it currently works beautifully with the viewport width set to 961. Google is forcing us to take that off though and use non-fixed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The guys that are commenting on your thread are being silly. If your meta tag stats that the width is 951, yet the width is more on the device, then THAT WILL make the site look weird. It all goes by the width of that device. If you are worries about SEO, a meta tag has NOTHING to do with that. Your content, your specific SEO meta tags (description, name, title, etc) will help there.

So, I love Google. WHY? Because they never lie and everything they do is amazing.

So, this is the way my meta tag looks on ALL websites I design or develop.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

WHY? Because real responsive websites need these.

All of your code depends on  your CSS file. So, maybe your css file is names style.css - great. Lets say you insert THREE logos in your header. One for desktop, one for tablet, one for mobile. AWESOME!

```
<img src="../logoMobile.png" class="logo_mobile" />
<img src="../logoTab.png" class="logo_tab"/>
<img src="../logo.png" class="logo"/>
```

This will be my CSS

```
.logo_tab, .logo_mobile  {display:none;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
.logo_tab {display:block;}
.logo, .logo_mobile  {display:none;}
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.logo_mobile {display:block;}
.logo, .logo_tab  {display:none;}
}
```

Hopefully you can read CSS and you will already know where I am going here. Basically, I design a logo that is suitable for tablet, mobile, and desktop. I usually use the same logo for tab and desktop, but that all depends.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not apply. As I stated in my question the site is not responsive, the content is scaled up for mobile with divs and media queries, we just have the menu to go and it will be fully mobile friendly. We need a solution to the viewport though http://www.homewetbar.com

Comment: OK, so you are worried that Google wont recognize it as a mobile friendly website? Then you might be better off and ditch the tables you used and recode everything with css. I dont mean to come off as ignorant, but making your site something it isn't just doesn't seem right. If Google asks for specific code to be used so its mobile friendly, then unfortunately that is the only way.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We plan on doing just that newJavaCoder, unfortunately we have a very sophisticated ecommerce site and well over 100 templates, it's not like a simple wordpress site. We're looking to completely replatform to a totally responsive site. We don't have the money for it yet, but we're saving for it. I'm told it will take 6 months to build out so we are doing the best we can for the mobile and tablet visitors until we can complete that.

Comment: Are you guys using a CMS or is the site coded for each item? Look into http://magento.com/ as they might be a awesome solution for you. Six months seems to be a lot of time to convert that, but hell, who am I? haha. Best of luck. With good SEO, ALL devices will find you.

Comment: Thanks we're looking at magento and also shopify. We use a ecommerce CMS but we have 2000+ pages, about 35 base templates and 50+ manual pages, think account pages, customer help etc.... It's gotten to be a massive overtaking to update things over the years. Replatforming is more complex than it seems, there is the design, the transferring of data, rekeying of some data, 301 urls, etc.  Definitely looking forward to when we can re-platform. In the meantime we've seen a nice 40%-50% increase in mobile conversion rates since we started the mobile upsizing. Customers definitely seem to like it.

Comment: Yup. Everyone uses their mobile device a lot more. Best of luck in your future.

Comment: I recommend leaving out the ```maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;``` Why? Because it pisses people off. They should be able to pinch and zoom, if they want to. Disabling the default function of any device creates a terrible user experience. They won't enjoy being on your site and may not visit it again.

Comment: @narong my sites are responsive. You don't need to zoom if the font is scaled to fit on the device.

Comment: @newJavaCoder Even with responsive sites, what's the point of disabling zoom? How do you benefit from doing so? I, for one, hate sites that disables it. Zooming makes it a lot easier to highlight and copy text.

Comment: I suppose  it's a personal preference. I hate zooming on responsive sites. To me it's almost like what's the point of going through the work of making it responsive if you give someone the ability to zoom.